# vb.net - using a CTE Query in VB.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have a working SQL Query with a CTE and I need that query in my vb.net application, but the problem is I get an error that states:

```
"Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'"
```

and the code is like this:

```
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sqlcmd As String = (";WITH q AS 
                                        (
                                         SELECT a.* 
                                         FROM SampleData AS a
                                         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                       FROM SampleData AS b
                                                       WHERE  a.Name = b.Name 
                                                         AND  a.Account= b.Account 
                                                         AND  a.Amount = -b.Amount)
                                         )
                            DELETE FROM q OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO SampleData2")



    If connDB.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        connDB.Open()
    End If

    Try

        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcmd, connDB)
        da.Fill(dt)
```

Any help on this? I can't find any solution to this.

Comment: What happens without the initial `;`?

Comment: it returns same error :(

Comment: Do other queries work using the same setup? Like if you change the query to something simple like "SELECT 1"?

Comment: Yes, I've tried removing the CTE and it works, but when i add it it returns an error

Comment: What's `SampleData2`? Is it really SQL Server? If it is, why not use SqlClient classes? Can you use stored procedures?

Comment: You could try to encapsulate this into a stored procedure and call the procedure from VBA instead of the CTE code directly.

Comment: Why are you using the fill method if your are not selecting anything. is `Select * from SampleData2` missing in your query? If not, use Deletecommand instead.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?  Can you provide some table set up scripts so we can recreate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function that works with a simple CTE, use this function to test your expression, just replace your CTE in it and see, you might need fix your query.

```
Public Sub RecursiveData()
    Dim connectionString As String = "Initial Catalog=DBName;Data Source=ServerName;uid=user;password=mypassword;Connection Timeout=50000"

    Dim cteQuery As String = ";WITH   cte " & vbCrLf &
        " AS(SELECT 1 AS n " & vbCrLf &
        " UNION ALL " & vbCrLf &
        " SELECT n + 1 " & vbCrLf &
        " FROM   cte " & vbCrLf &
        " WHERE  n <50 " & vbCrLf &
        " ) " & vbCrLf &
        " SELECT n " & vbCrLf &
        " FROM cte where n <= 5; "

    Using _con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using _cmd As New SqlCommand(cteQuery, _con)

            _con.Open()

            Using rdr As SqlDataReader = _cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While rdr.Read()
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetValue(0).ToString())
                End While

                rdr.Close()
            End Using

            _con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```